# Want to share an existing Mac OS desktop to several viewers over VNC

Tags: macos, vnc, screen-sharing

I want to give a demo to people remotely.  I want them to be able to use any VNC client to view my current Mac desktop.  Can I use the built-in screen sharing features to do that?  I'm using Mountain Lion (10.8.2).  I don't want to set up a special "guest" account.  I don't want to share my MacOS password with them.  Everything I try under "Screen Sharing" gives the VNC user a Mac login screen, and doesn't connect to the existing desktop.  When I enable the "remote management feature" it connects directly to the existing session with full control.  I don't want all the viewers of my demo to have full control of the desktop, although that may be an acceptable work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to be useful, but if you look under "Options" for remote management, you can  set whether viewers connecting with Screen Sharing can "Observe", or "Control".